# Adding a new line break in message using Basic Authentication with C#

Tags: c#, api, basic-authentication

```
            var username = _settingService.GetSettingByKey<string>("Stiply.Username");
            var password = _settingService.GetSettingByKey<string>("Stiply.Password");
            string uenter code hereri = "https://api.stiply.nl/v1/sign_requests/" + requestKey + "/signers";
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
            String encoded = System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetBytes(username + ":" + password));
            WebRequest.Create(uri);
            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + encoded);
            request.KeepAlive = false;
            request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version11;
            request.PreAuthenticate = true;
            request.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = true;
            request.ContentType = "application/json";
            request.Method = "POST";
            var stiplyRequest = new StiplySigner();
            stiplyRequest.SignerEmail = contactEmail;
            stiplyRequest.SignerSignatureFields.Add(new StiplySignerField() { Name = "signature_" + signCount });
            stiplyRequest.SignerTextFields.Add(new StiplySignerField() { Name = "text_" + signCount });
            stiplyRequest.Language = languageId;
            stiplyRequest.Message = contactMessage;

            string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(stiplyRequest);

            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
            {
                streamWriter.Write(output);
                streamWriter.Flush();
                streamWriter.Close();
            }
```

This is the code i am using in contactMessage variable i am sending the following text:

> Beste relatie,
>
> Hierbij ontvangt je het concept contract.
>
> En nog een zin na een enter.
>
> Alvast dank, Interforce

but when an email is returned from an api is shows up like following:

> Beste relatie,
>
> Hierbij ontvangt je het concept contract.
>
> En nog een zin na een enter.
>
> Alvast dank, Interforce

can please someone guide me.

Comment: Both are looking same

Comment: @viveknuna yes exactly what is happening with me, because i posted multiple line spaces in first contactMessage, but all the extra lines are trimed.

Comment: Can you check in `output ` variable whether you are getting multiple lines

Comment: yes there I am getting multiple lines but on view level, they are not.